# Journey Builder Test Mode does not work for Salesforce Data Entry Source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am not sure if this is an issue or if there is something incorrectly configured in our Journey, but we cannot see any leads or contacts flowing through our customer journey which is based on *Salesforce Data* in *Test Mode*. *Activating* the same journey gets customers flowing through the journey and the email gets sent too. However, the *test mode* does not work with *Salesforce Data Entry Source*. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supposed to work.

Here's the documentation link for [Salesforce Data Event](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/using_the_salesforce_sales_and_service_cloud_event/).

Under the *Considerations* section:

> Test mode does not support Salesforce Data Events.

Comment: Thanks Atheri! I missed that document. Thank you for directing me to it!

Answer (score 1):

Test mode doesn't work with salesforce data entry events. It's a known limitation within test mode